# Is it slower to load an embedded video rather than from its source?

Tags: video, internet, speed, video-streaming

It would make sense that a video that is embedded in a site (like if I were to post a YouTube video on this question or a blog post) would be slower to load because it has to be redirected from a YouTube server first. Is that true?

Is it slower to load an embedded video rather than from its source?

Comment: Depends on how it's "embedded"! And slower than what? Do you think the YouTube HTML code resides on the same server as the one which hosts the videos?

Comment: In the case of embedded youtubes, the majority of the data (all the video data) still comes right from the source , the youtube servers, so there is little diference there. another dns resolve. Any additional or unnessisry activity going on the page, vrses what might be going on when at the orignal source might be a concideration.  For me uncapping all the off buttons for active-x and scripts at some unknown blog was the only concideration, not the speed.